# Is there a way to classify all power-invariant graphs?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Suppose $G = (V, E)$ is a finite undirected simple graph. Let’s, define the $n$-th power of a graph (where $n \in \mathbb{N}$) as graph $G^n = (V, E_n)$, where $$E_n = \begin{cases} E & \quad n = 1 \\ \{\{v, w\} \in P(V)|v \neq w \text{ and } \exists u \in V, \{v, u\} \in E_{n - 1}, \{u, w\} \in E \} & \quad n > 1 \end{cases}$$

Let’s call a graph $G$ power-invariant iff $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$, $G$ is isomorphic to $G^n$.

Is there a way to classify all power-invariant graphs?

I know, that all full graphs $K_n$ with $n \geq 3$ are power-invariant, however, I have heard of neither other examples of power invariant graphs, nor proofs that there aren’t ones.

Comment: Note that if $G$ is connected then there is a $d \gt 0$ such that $G^d \cong K_n$ where $n$ is the number of vertices

Comment: @hbm If $G^d$ is defined in the usual way, $G^d$ is a complete graph whenever $d\ge\operatorname{diam}(G)$. However, under the OP's peculiar definition, if $G$ is a bipartite graph, then $G^d$ is bipartite whenever $d$ is odd.

Comment: According to your (unusual) definition of $G^n$, the complete graph $K_2$ is not power-invariant. If $G$ has two vertices $v,w$ one one edge $\{v,w\}$, then your $G^2$ has two loop-edges $\{v,v\}$ and $\{w,w\}$, but no edge $\{v,w\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's obvious (or, if not, at least easy to show) that this property is closed under disjoint union, so the interesting question is to characterise the *irreducible* finite power-invariant graphs.

In addition to complete graphs $K_n$ for $n \ge 3$ we can list the trivial graph $K_1$. We can also observe that all odd cycles $C_{2a+1}$ satisfy $G^2 \approx G$, but they aren't power-invariant for $2a+1 > 3$ because $G^3$ is regular with degree 4.

---

**Each connected component of a finite power-invariant graph must remain a single connected component when raised to any power**. Proof: if $C$ is a connected component of a finite power-invariant graph $G$ and $C^k$ has more than one connected component, $G^k$ must have more connected components than $G$. (Clearly two connected components of $G$ won't merge into one connected component of $G^k$ to compensate). But that contradicts the assumption that $G$ is power-invariant.

---

**If $C$ is a connected component of a finite power-invariant graph $G$, there must be some $k > 1$ such that $C^k$ is isomorphic to $C$**. Proof: consider the directed (non-simple, because it may have loops) graph $\Gamma$ whose vertices are graphs with the same number of vertices as $C$ and where each vertex $V$ has one edge, to $V^2$. $\Gamma$ is finite and each of its connected components is a finite cycle or loop with zero or more inverted trees feeding into it. If there is no $k > 1$ such that $C^k \approx C$ then $C$ cannot be in a cycle. Now, $G^2 \approx G$, so $G$ must contain a connected component $C'$ such that $C'^2 \approx C$, or $C' \to C$ in $\Gamma$. Similarly, it must contain a connected component $C'' \to C'$, etc. But because $C$ is an internal node of a finite tree, we can't chain backwards indefinitely.

Define the *order* of $C$ as the smallest $k > 1$ such that $C^k \approx C$.

---

**If $C$ is a connected component of a finite power-invariant graph $G$, $C^2$ is isomorphic to $C$**. Proof: we know that each connected component of $G$ has a finite order. Suppose $C$ is a connected component of $G$ with order $k$. Since $G \approx G^a$ for each $a \in \{1, \ldots, k-1\}$, $G$ contains a connected component isomorphic to $C^a$ for each $a \in \{1, \ldots, k-1\}$. None of these connected components can be isomorphic to each other without contradicting the definition of $k$ as the order of $C$.

Let $p$ be a prime factor of $k-1$. In $G^p$ these connected components become $G^p, G^{2p}, \ldots, G^{(k-1)p}$, which are $p$ copies each of $\frac{k-1}{p}$ isomorphically distinct connected components. In particular, $(C^{k-1})^p \approx C^{k-1}$. Therefore the number of copies of $C^{k-1}$ in $G^p$ is at least as many as the number of copies of both $C^{(k-1)/p}$ and $C^{k-1}$ in $G$. Since there's at least one copy of $C^{(k-1)/p}$, $G$ is either not finite or not isomorphic to $G^p$.

Therefore $k-1$ must be coprime to all primes, so $k-1 = 1$ and $k=2$.

**Corollary**: the irreducible finite power-invariant graphs consist of a single connected component.

---

**Suppose $G$ is a connected finite power-invariant graph. Then it is a complete graph.**

Proof: the only connected graphs on fewer than three vertices are complete graphs, so there is nothing to prove in those cases and we need only consider the case that $G$ has at least three vertices. $G$ cannot be bipartite, for then $G^2$ would not be connected, so $G$ must contain an odd cycle $u_1 \to u_2 \to \cdots \to u_{2k+1} \to u_1$. For all $a \ge 2k$ there is a trail $u_1 \to^a u_{2k+1}$: if $a$ is even then the trail goes $u_1 \to u_2 \to \cdots \to u_{2k+1} (\to u_{2k} \to u_{2k+1})^{a-2k}$, and if $a$ is odd then the trail goes $u_1 \to u_{2k+1} (\to u_{2k} \to u_{2k+1})^{a-1}$. It follows that if we consider two arbitrary vertices $v$ and $w$ then $\{v,w\} \in E_{2n+2k-2}$: there is a path $v \to^i u_1$ for some $i \le n-1$, a path $u_{2k+1} \to^j w$ for some $j \le n-1$, and a trail $u_1 \to^{2k+(n-1-i)+(n-1-j)} u_{2k+1}$. Therefore $G^{2n+2k-2} \approx K_n$.

Comment: Interesting follow-up question: for what connected graphs do we have $G \approx G^2$? They clearly include the power-invariant complete graphs and the odd cycles, and up to 15 vertices there are no others.